# Comodo Firewall asks to restart the computer. How to refuse?

Tags: windows-7, firewall, comodo-firewall

Comodo Firewall asks me to restart the computer. In the dialog box it seems that I can only postpone the reminder. Is there any way to turn off the reminder for ever?

[image]

[image]

I use Comodo Firewall with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a way to do this. Eventually I turned off "Automatic Updates". Now I just update everything I need to (not just Comodo) at a time where I can reboot several times if necessary.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, sounds like a good workaround.

Comment: Yeah, but not good enough for an answer ;) I'm also stuck with a tethered mobile connection with a fixed monthly bandwidth so I check how much bandwidth I have left for updates just before the rollover and then decide what to update ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill should be an answer.

Comment: @Moab OK. You've persuaded me. Answered.

Comment: The same way you postpone Windows Update reboot popups: By postponing them, 4 hours at a time. It’s not like it’ll restart by itself, it just annoys you.

Comment: @DanielB I am glad to say I have used Windows for ~20 years and I have never used Windows Update :)

Comment: I’m not sure whether that’s something to be proud of. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there any way to turn off the reminder for ever?

I had the same problem and was unable to find a solution (after much searching).

Eventually I decided to turn off Comodo's "Automatic Updates" and manually update it at the same time as I manually update the OS and other programs.

Note:

- I have a tethered mobile connection with a fixed monthly bandwidth so I check how much bandwidth I have left for updates just before the rollover and then decide what to update.

---

#### How do I turn off Automatic Updates?

1. Right click on the Comodo icon in the system tray
2. Select "Open"
3. Click on "Tasks"
4. Click on "Advanced Tasks"
5. Click on "Open Advance Settings"
6. Click on "Updates"
7. Uncheck "Automatically download program updates"

---

#### How do I manually update?

1. Right click on the Comodo icon in the system tray
2. Select "Open"
3. Click "Update"

Comment: Easy money!!!!!

Comment: @Moab lol ... I'm already rep capped today ;)

Comment: Well that sucks!